# Call url and save data after every x-time-periode into csv-file

Tags: python, csv, url, data-storage

```
run_time = 60
run_until = time.time() + run_time
while time.time() < run_until:
    if run_time % 5 == 0:
        url = 'URL'
        csv_file = open('cam_data1.csv', 'a')
        req = requests.get(url)
        data = req.json()
        csv_file.write(str(data))
        csv_file.close()
```

This is the code I wrote. It calls the url and saves its output data in a csv file every 5 seconds.
The output-data is a json and looks like this:

{'blood_pressure_diastolic_value': 70.0, 'blood_pressure_systolic_value': 120.0, 'heart_rate_value': 120.0, 'respiratory_rate_value': 55.0, 'sat02_value': 95.0}

I have to compare the values with another dataset. The problem is that the code puts all the data in one cell. This makes working with it hard because tracing the timestamp for each data is complicated.

I want each new output to be stored in a new row and each of the arguments to have its own column. So 5 columns and a new row for every output.

Can anybody help me with this or show me an alternative way to access the data as it is?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
import time

wait_seconds = 60
while True:
    url = 'URL'
    csv_file = open('cam_data1.csv', 'a')
    req = requests.get(url)
    data = req.json()
    csv_file.write(str(data))
    csv_file.close()
    time.sleep(wait_seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

A Good way of doing it would be`:

```
import time

run_time = 60
while time.time() < (time.time() + run_time):
    url = 'URL'
    
    # context manager close the file automatically
    with open('cam_data1.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        req = requests.get(url)
        data = req.json()  # this returns a dictionary
        # we only take value of the dict not the key (title of your columns)
        for value in data.value():
           csv_file.write(f"{value};")  
           # IMPORTANT if you want 'classic' CSV replace the semi-colon by a coma
        csv_file.write("\n")  # This create a new line
        
    time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
   import time

   run_time = 30
   run_until = time.time() + run_time
   while time.time() < run_until:
       url = 'http://xxx'
       csv_file = open('cam_data2.csv', 'a')
       req = requests.get(url)
       data = req.json()
       csv_file.write(str(data))
       csv_file.write('\n')
       time.sleep(5)
       csv_file.close()
```

now my problem is that I am working with this tipe of data:
{"blood_pressure_diastolic_value":70.0,"blood_pressure_systolic_value":120.0}

and the csv_file.write() method only allows me to save it as a string. Is there any other way that the json structure stays as it is so that I can later recall the value of each item?